# Complex sorting in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, tableview

I have two arrays:

```
var sections: [SectionContent] = []
var cells: [CellContent] = []
```

Of those two arrays, one is nested inside the other one:

```
struct SectionContent {
    let sectionDate: Date
    let sectionContent: [CellContent]
}

struct CellContent {
    let cellDate: Date?
    var formattedDate: String {
        guard let text = cellDate else { return "" }
        return DateFormatter.stringDate.string(from: text)
    }
}

extension DateFormatter {
    static let stringDate: DateFormatter = {
        let formatterDate = DateFormatter()
        formatterDate.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
        return formatterDate
    }()
}
```

The '**sections**' array displays the date as the section header in tableView.

The '**cells**' array displays the respective data assigned to that date.

The date is set in a separate viewController from which I do the unwindSegue to the first viewController.

I managed to sort the sections by date thru including this code inside of the unwindSegue:

```
sections.sort { $0.sectionDate < $1.sectionDate }
```

**Question: Given my configuration, how do I sort cells within one section by the corresponding time (earlier time at the top and later at the bottom)?**

[image]

Edit: This is how I construct the Section:

```
func sortByDate() {
    sections.removeAll()
    let dates = cells.reduce(into: Set<Date>()) { result, cells in
        let date = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: cells.cellDate!)
        result.insert(date) }
    for date in dates {
        let dateComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
        var sortedContent: [CellContent] = []
        cells.forEach { cells in
            let contComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: cells.cellDate!)
            if contComp == dateComp {
                sortedContent.append(cells) } }
        let newSection = SectionContent(sectionDate: date, sectionContent: sortedContent)
        sections.append(newSection) } }
```

Comment: How do you construct the `Section`? You need to sort there. Or iterate over each section and change the order of the cell, then sort on the section.

Comment: I edited the question per your question

Comment: Here `let newSection = SectionContent(sectionDate: date, sectionContent: sortedContent)`, I guess that "sortedContext" isn't really sorted.

Comment: 'sortedContent' in a sense that the dates in cells are juxtaposed to dates in sections, so that the correct cell is assigned to the correct section. It doesn't do the sorting of cells by date within one section though.

Comment: let me answer this

Comment: Why is `cellDate` optional, how could it ever be part of a section if the value is nil?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: In formatedDate it complained that the initializer for conditional binding must have optional type

Comment: Remove the `guard` statement then instead of making the property optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort the sections as you're already doing it

```
//sort the sections
sections.sort { $0.sectionDate < $1.sectionDate }
```

then sort the contents like this

```
//sort the contents
for index in 0..<sections.count {
    sections[index].sectionContent.sort { $0.cellDate ?? .now < $1.cellDate ?? .now }
}
```

note that you must change `sectionContent` to a var for the second sort to work

```
struct SectionContent {
    let sectionDate: Date
    var sectionContent: [CellContent] //<--- must be var not let
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both answers work. So how do I accept both as correct answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var sections: [SectionContent] = SectionContent.demo()
    
    // just give unsorted/sorted sections to this function and it will return sorted section  
    func sortedContent(unsorted:[SectionContent]) -> [SectionContent] {
        var sorted = [SectionContent]()
        sorted = unsorted.sorted(by: { $0.sectionDate < $1.sectionDate})
        sorted.enumerated().forEach { index,section in
            sorted[index].sectionContent = section.sectionContent.sorted(by: { $0.cellDate ?? Date() < $1.cellDate ?? Date()})
        }
        return sorted
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedContent(unsorted: sections).count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let _section = sortedContent(unsorted: sections)[section]
        return _section.sectionDate.formatted()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let section = sortedContent(unsorted: sections)[indexPath.section]
        let row = section.sectionContent[indexPath.row]
    }
    
}

struct SectionContent {
    
    let sectionDate: Date
    var sectionContent: [CellContent]
    
    static func demo() -> [SectionContent] {
        return [SectionContent(sectionDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-46000),
                               sectionContent: [CellContent(cellDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(4000)),
                                                CellContent(cellDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(3000)),
                                                CellContent(cellDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(1000)),
                                                CellContent(cellDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60))]),
                SectionContent(sectionDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-76000),
                                       sectionContent: [CellContent(cellDate: Date())]),
                SectionContent(sectionDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-6000),
                                       sectionContent: [CellContent(cellDate: Date())]),
                SectionContent(sectionDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(-50),
                                       sectionContent: [CellContent(cellDate: Date())])]
    }
    
    
}
```

**Just give unsorted/sorted sections to this function and it will return sorted section**

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add an explanation of the code.